# Do not show browser and OS in Selenium console output

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

I am running Selenium tests (with Protractor) on several browser at the same time to speed up the testing.

Jenkins starts the tests and receives the output in a console. To make things more readable I am figuring out how to show the test results differently. With xunit, html, or another reporter (I am using Mocha as testframework for Protractor). Any tips are welcome here.

The problem: when running test simultaneously on multiple browsers Selenium outputs the used browser and Operating System between the results.
Example:

```
[launcher] Running 13 instances of WebDriver


[chrome ANY #1e] 
[chrome ANY #1e] Using the selenium server at http://172.20.20.208:4444/wd/hub/
[chrome ANY #1e] 
[chrome ANY #1e]
```

This makes the output less readably. Plus when I choose to print the results those lines are not put between html tags.

Is there a way to hide this information?
Or any other ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to not rely on the console for recording your test results.

Jenkins has the ability to output the test results using the [JUNIT Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin). Install the plugin (if it's not already) and then add a post build action and publish as a JUnit test result report.

Or you could use a separate test reporting framework like [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/). Here's an [example of how to use Allure](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/59-html-reporting).